# port 25060 failed: FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host and can't connect to Digital Ocean server

Tags: postgresql, ssl, digital-ocean, pgadmin-4, pg-hba.conf

We did not have any issue but did not run the Digital ocean DB seeding for months and when the team tried to re-do it, we experienced the below error within the Pgadmin. We've been blocked for over 1 week now.

Full error:
connection to server at "DBNAME.b.db.ondigitalocean.com" (IP address), port 25060 failed: FATAL: pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "IP address", user "NAME", database "NAME", SSL encryption

connection to server at "DBNAME.b.db.ondigitalocean.com" (IP Address), port 25060 failed: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "IP Address", user "NAME", database "NAME", no encryption

Does the order that you type out the updated information into the pg_hba.conf file matter? If so what is the correct order?

What are the steps that I can take to resolve the issue? Do any of the articles referenced already actually provide the solution?

The current pg_hba.conf file looks like this. After we tried making the changes recommended in the links, our postgresql stopped working all together so we reverted back to the original file.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
  local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
  host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
 host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
  local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
  host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
  host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264560/need-help-understanding-the-error-message-error-connecting-to-database-fatal
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161104/pgadmin-postgresql-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320468/postgresql-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host-ipv6-user-user-databas

We have looked into somewhat related articles here on stack exchange.
Tried changing it to event listeners is * and changed to host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 with trusted per user @joanalo's answer
Its still saying the same error and we expected the error to be resolved.

Also another thing is that in our Digital Ocean server - the SSL is default set to required and it is not allowing a change. This same required is stuck and not allowing it to be changed within the SSH portion of the Postgresql. Some folks have indicated that the SSL needs to be changed to true or that the reason for the issue is a mismatch between the SSL security in Digital Ocean versus Postgresql. But we are not able to attempt a change.
How would we be able to change the SSL to true if that is what will help resolve the issue?

Comment: Unless you made up port number 25060 yourself I'm assuming this is some Digital Ocean service which provides its own access control. Their documentation is pretty good. Start here https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/databases/